# Search on linqDataSource requires 2 clicks sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, search

I have a page with linqdatasource and a gridView. 
There are several textBoxes to enter search conditions.
LinqDataSource_OnSelecting event filters the query by something like this:

```
var query = from d in db.PersonData 
            select d;

if (textBoxName.Text != "")
    var query = query.where(p => p == textBoxName.Text); 

if (textBoxPhone.Text != "")
    var query = query.where(p => p == textBoxPhone.Text); 

e.Result = query;
```

And btnSearch_Click event has the following code:

```
gridView.DataBind();
```

It works pretty good most times, but sometimes I have to click search button twice to see the results. First time I click search, gridView is empty! Second time I have correct results.
Hope you will clarify why it is sometimes goes that way.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that your button event is firing the first time you click? Is there an error you are catching somewhere?

Comment: There is no any error. The thing I dont understand is that most times search works as required. In fact I have the similiar problem like this:[link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10070097/search-on-linq-datasource-not-working-correctly.aspx) but there is no solution to my problem on this site.

Answer (score 1):

if you binding `Gridview-Datasource` manually and not use `dataset` you must always bind `Gridview-Datasource` in page load.

> In web (asp.net) it's not like Win-app, you can't bind Datasource to grid without Page-Load event.

*`As solution:`* you can use `Updatepanle` and put Your Grid in that. and use `GridName.DataBind()` after binding.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason you're getting blanks only, sometimes, is that you are on a page beyond which the search will yield results.

*E.g.*: you're on page 10 of the unfiltered results, hit `Search,` and get only 5 pages' worth of results. Thus, the page you're currently viewing (10) is blank.

After the LINQ statement has completed, you need to reset the `GridView` back to the first page.

A second (possible) problem is that you cannot guarantee the order of all event handlers. (See [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events).) *I.e.*, you cannot count on either `LinqDataSource_OnSelecting` or `btnSearch_Click` firing first, and you have the `DataBind` in the `Click` handler. **Eliminate** the `btnSearch_Click` event handler (or leave it blank) and use [`LinqDataSource.OnSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.selected.aspx), instead, which will definitely fire after `LinqDataSource.OnSelecting`:

```
protected void LinqDataSource_Selected(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {
  gridView.DataBind();
  gridView.PageIndex = 0;  // back to beginning when searching
}
```